# Browserify throws an error with my JSON

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs, browserify

Could anyone tell me why Browserify might not like this code?

```
{
  "months":[
    {
      "name":"January",
      "value":0,
      "days":31
    },
    {
      "name":"February",
      "value":1,
      "days":28
    },
    {
      "name":"March",
      "value":2,
      "days":31
    },
    {
      "name":"April",
      "value":3,
      "days":30
    },
    {
      "name":"May",
      "value":4,
      "days":31
    },
    {
      "name":"June",
      "value":5,
      "days":30
    },
    {
      "name":"July",
      "value":6,
      "days":31
    },
    {
      "name":"August",
      "value":7,
      "days":31
    },
    {
      "name":"September",
      "value":8,
      "days":30
    },
    {
      "name":"October",
      "value":9,
      "days":31
    },
    {
      "name":"November",
      "value":10,
      "days":30
    },
    {
      "name":"December",
      "value":11,
      "days":31
    }
  ],
  "times":[
    {
      "name":"1200 AM",
      "value":0
    },
    {
      "name":"100 AM",
      "value":1
    },
    {
      "name":"200 AM",
      "value":2
    },
    {
      "name":"300 AM",
      "value":3
    },
    {
      "name":"400 AM",
      "value":4
    },
    {
      "name":"500 AM",
      "value":5
    },
    {
      "name":"600 AM",
      "value":6
    },
    {
      "name":"700 AM",
      "value":7
    },
    {
      "name":"800 AM",
      "value":8
    },
    {
      "name":"900 AM",
      "value":9
    },
    {
      "name":"1000 AM",
      "value":10
    },
    {
      "name":"1100 AM",
      "value":11
    },
    {
      "name":"1200 PM",
      "value":12
    },
    {
      "name":"100 PM",
      "value":13
    },
    {
      "name":"200 PM",
      "value":14
    },
    {
      "name":"300 PM",
      "value":15
    },
    {
      "name":"400 PM",
      "value":16
    },
    {
      "name":"500 PM",
      "value":17
    },
    {
      "name":"600 PM",
      "value":18
    },
    {
      "name":"700 PM",
      "value":19
    },
    {
      "name":"800 PM",
      "value":20
    },
    {
      "name":"900 PM",
      "value":21
    },
    {
      "name":"1000 PM",
      "value":22
    },
    {
      "name":"1100 PM",
      "value":23
    }
  ],
  "years":[
    2015,
    2016,
    2017,
    2018,
    2019,
    2020,
    2021,
    2022,
    2023,
    2024,
    2025
  ]
}
```

I get the following error when `require`ing this file (filename is dateTimes.json):

```
Error: Parse Error: Line 2: Unexpected token : in "/SkillfulCactus/client/scripts/data/dateTimes.js" while parsing file: /SkillfulCactus/client/scripts/data/dateTimes.js
```

I've linted the file and run it through any validator I could find. I'm at a loss as to why this error is being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the file name from:

> dateTimes.js

...to:

> dateTimes.json

And make sure you have the most recent version of Browserify because there was a [bug in older versions](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/616).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried renaming it to a .json. I'll check which version I'm using.

Comment: Actually, that works - it looks the bug may have been in the older version.